# BitNot does not flip bits in the way I expected

Tags: binary

Can anyone explain why the last result in these statements is not the bit-flipped version of arr?

```
(Debug) In[189]:= arr = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}

(Debug) Out[189]= {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}

(Debug) In[190]:= FromDigits[%, 2]

(Debug) Out[190]= 34

(Debug) In[191]:= BitNot[%]

(Debug) Out[191]= -35

(Debug) In[192]:= IntegerDigits[%, 2, 8]

(Debug) Out[192]= {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
```

Comment: _"IntegerDigits[n] discards the sign of n."_

Comment: Is there a work around?

Comment: not any I know of.

Comment: BitNot should yield 221

Comment: I removed the `bugs` tag, since that requires verification by other users.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, bc888! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

Comment: Integers can have arbitrary length, so how many leading zeros should be flipped? The documentation clarifies: "Integers are assumed to be represented in two's complement form, with an unlimited number of digits, so that `BitNot[n]` is simply equivalent to `-1-n`."

Comment: `UnitBox[arr]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise operators - Hamlet for Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18358/bitwise-operators-hamlet-for-mathematica)

Comment: If you just want to flip "bits" in an array of 1/0 elements without the need to go between integer representation, just use `BitXor[1,array]`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in function to generate the two's complement representation. Easy to implement though.

```
twosComplement[x_, n_] := IntegerDigits[2^x - n, 2, n]
twosComplement[35, 8]
(* {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
twosComplement[x_, n_] := UnitBox@IntegerDigits[x, 2, n]
twosComplement[35, 8]
```

> {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}

Answer (score 7):

Without using `IntegerDigits[]`:

```
With[{n = 34}, 
     {n, BitXor[BitShiftLeft[1, BitLength[n]] - 1, n]} // BaseForm[#, 2] &]
   {100010₂, 11101₂}

With[{n = 34, p = 8},
     {n, BitXor[BitShiftLeft[1, p] - 1, n]} // BaseForm[#, 2] &]
   {100010₂, 11011101₂}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
FlipBits[num_Integer, len_.] := 
 Module[{arr}, arr = IntegerDigits[num, 2, len];
  1 - arr]
```